# Unexpected behavior with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to write a parser that detects bibliography footnotes, using regular expressions. But a particular RE is not working, and I cannot figure out why. Here is the code where I isolated the problem.

```
import re
PATTERN = "[\\w ]+, [\\w ]+, (\\d+(\\-\\d+)?)\\."

match_A = re.search(PATTERN, "Author, Some Book, 51–66.")
match_B = re.search(PATTERN, "Author, Some Book, 60-61.")

print(match_A != None)
print(match_B != None)

SUB_PATTERN = "\\d+(\\-\\d+)?"

match_C = re.search(SUB_PATTERN, "51–66")
match_D = re.search(SUB_PATTERN, "60–61")

print(match_C != None)
print(match_D != None)
```

The result is:

```
False
True
True
True
```

But I expect to obtain all `True`.
Can anybody reproduce this issue, or explain what is happening to me?

I am working on Windows 10. My Python version:

```
Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Comment: Would the `Author` really only be one word?  Can you add more sample data?

Comment: In the definition of `match_A`, you have an en dash, not a hyphen, in the string being searched. (If you look carefully, it's every so slightly longer.)

Comment: You also have en dashes in the calls to `match_C` and `match_D`, but it's not a problem there because the missing hyphen doesn't prevent a trailing `.` from being matched.

Comment: Changing the pattern to "[\\w ]+, [\\w ]+, (\\d+([-\u2013]\\d+)?)\\." might make it more obvious what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dashes are different, the first one is a "–" ("en dash") and the second one is a "-" ("hyphen"). If you don't believe me, google each one. You can put them into a character class:

```py
PATTERN = "[\\w ]+, [\\w ]+, (\\d+([–-]\\d+)?)\\."
```